# TYPO3 - own login

Tags: authentication, typo3-8.x

I have an array with user and email. I would like to link this with TYPO3 with the fe_users. That means I have written my own login form.

That is, if the user does not exist, entries should be made in the fe_users. If it exists, the login process simply continues. So far no problem.
But how does the user stay logged in? How does the TYPO3 process? I can not find anything about Google or am I looking wrong?

Answer (score 0):

a TYPO3 user stays logged in as there is a session-cookie with the login-credentials. This cookie is refreshed on each server-request.

if your hook is executed and inserts the missing user data you need to restart the login-process to enable TYPO3 to do a normal login process (against the now filled database).